# Redux Testing - ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, mocha.js, redux

I'm currently having a lot of trouble running tests on my redux actions. The test passes but I get the following error each time it is ran:

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

I also got an error before which was:

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I fixed this by using isomorphic-fetch. Anyway I am unsure on how I should configure Mocha to run these front end tests. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**Mocha test command:**

```
mocha -w test/test_helper.js test/*.spec.js
```

---

**test_helper.js:**

```
require('babel-register')();
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;

Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

documentRef = document;
```

---

**auth.actions.spec.js**

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import * as actions from '../client/app/actions/auth'
import * as types from '../client/app/constants/ActionTypes'
import nock from 'nock'
import chai from 'chai'
import sinon from 'sinon'

var expect = chai.expect

import { SERVER_API } from './config'

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('auth actions', () => {

afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll()
})

it('creates LOGIN_REQUEST and LOGINSUCCESS when correct username and password provided', () => {

    nock(SERVER_API)
    .post('/login', {
      username: 'test',
      password: 'password'
    })
    .reply(200, {
      token: 'TOKEN'
    });

    const expectedActions = [
    { 
        type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST,
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        creds: {
          username: 'test',
         password: 'password'
        } 
    },
    { 
        type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        token: 'TOKEN'
    }
    ]

    const INITAL_STATE = {
      isFetching: false,
      isAuthenticated: false
    }
    const store = mockStore(INITAL_STATE)

    return    store.dispatch(actions.loginUser({username:'test',password:'password'}))
       .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions)
       })
    })
})
```

---

**auth.js**

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import 'es6-promise'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

import {
  LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE
} from '../constants/ActionTypes.js'

import { SERVER_PORT } from '../constants/config'


function requestLogin(creds) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
    isFetching: true,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    creds
  }
}

function receiveLogin(user) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    token: user.token
  }
}

function loginError(message) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    message
  }
}

export function loginUser(creds) {

  let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: `username=${creds.username}&password=${creds.password}`
  }

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestLogin(creds))
    return fetch('http://localhost:'+SERVER_PORT+'/api/login', config)
      .then(response =>
        response.json()
        .then(user => ({ user, response }))
      ).then(({ user, response }) =>  {
        if (!response.ok) {
          dispatch(loginError(user.message))
          return Promise.reject(user)
        }
        else {
          dispatch(receiveLogin(user))
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token) //offending line
          dispatch(push('foo'))
        }
      }).catch(err => console.log("Error: ", err))
  }
}
```

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty straightforward error, you can't use `localStorage` on your mocha tests because `window.localStorage` isn't defined. There are two ways to fix this. The more "canon" way would be to move that `localStorage` call from your action because this is a side-effect which is an anti-pattern in redux actions. Instead you should have middleware that catches this action and sets the `localStorage`.

By doing that, you already eliminate the issue of testing this action.

If, however, you don't know how to do that and don't think it wise, then you can "fake" `localStorage` by making a global variable at the top of your mocha test file which creates a fake `localStorage`. I recommend against this one but it's definitely a solution that could work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and advice. I thought this was why but wasn't sure if I could use test_helper instead to fake localstorage. I will definitely try using middleware instead. Thank you.

Comment: @ZekeDroid One would also have to create the `setItem` method within the `localStorage` global variable in that case right?

Comment: Amongst other methods, yes

Comment: @ZekeDroid I'm new to react redux and am using redux sagas. I'm not really sure what you mean by using middleware. I moved my call to localStorage into a global function which gets called in the saga, would that be considered a clean solution?

Comment: No because your sagas now depend on `localStorage`. I would read up on redux middleware: https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware