# Why is localStorage not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, passport.js

I'm trying to adapt a reactjs + passportjs implementation I found on github for my project. The original project works just fine on my computer, but when any of the pages has a call to localStorage.getItem(), the computer throws an error. I find this strange because shouldn't this error also get thrown the first time I run the original project from github? Anyway, here is the file that's giving me problems right now:

```
class Auth {

  /**
   * Authenticate a user. Save a token string in Local Storage
   *
   * @param {string} token
   */
  static authenticateUser(token) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  /**
   * Check if a user is authenticated - check if a token is saved in Local Storage
   *
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  static isUserAuthenticated() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
  }

  /**
   * Deauthenticate a user. Remove a token from Local Storage.
   *
   */
  static deauthenticateUser() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  /**
   * Get a token value.
   *
   * @returns {string}
   */

  static getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

}

export default Auth;
```

I would've assumed that when I make a call to isUserAuthenticated() without anything else set up that it would find `null` because there's no token there and then it would just return false, but instead it's throwing this error:

`ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

Any help you can give is definitely welcome. Thanks!

You can find the original example [here](https://github.com/vladimirponomarev/authentication-in-react-apps/tree/master/part-2-json-web-token).

Comment: "but instead it's throwing this error"  What is the error message, specifically?

Comment: `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

Comment: Is there any chance you're running this in Node or during unit testing, instead of in a browser?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878245/referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined-in-reactjs-build  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398427/redux-testing-referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined

Comment: I don't think it's the same problem. I am running this in the browser. Not a mocha test or anything like that

Comment: OK, it was worth a shot; I don't have any idea how localStorage could be undefined in a regular browser context, sorry.

Comment: what he is trying to find out is whether you are doing any server-side rendering, case in which there is no browser storage - where a solution to avoid this would be to write an adapter

Comment: Ahhhh. Yes we are. That must be the problem